# Is there a mistake in the latest HTML specification?

Tags: html

I wanted to know if tables are allowed inside anchors like this:

```
<a>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello!</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

Because some people on the internet say it is allowed while others say it is not.

I looked under [§4.5.1 The a element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) and it says the content model is "transparent". Then I looked into [3.2.5.3 Transparent content models](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent) to see what that means. And it says:

> [...] the elements required in the part of the content model that is "transparent" are the same elements as required in the part of the content model of the parent [...]

They use the word **required** but I think it must be the word **allowed**.

Inside the 'a' element no elements are required at all. Instead the question is which elements are allowed. Or am I wrong?

Note that this question is not about whether tables are allowed inside anchors but instead if there is a mistake in section 3.2.5.3 of the HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They use the word required but I think it must be the word allowed.

well, you just answered yourself with the next sentence:

> Inside the 'a' element no elements are required at all.

and no

> Instead the question is which elements are allowed.

that's not the question of the content model of the spec.

the spec says that an `a`-tag can't contain other interactive elements, which would then make those elements not-allowed.

also to the tables inside links question: as long as the table does not contain any interactive elements (buttons, inputs, other links etc.) you can put a table inside your `a`-tag (if that's a good idea is another question), the spec itself even gives that exact example:

> The a element can be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g., buttons or other links).

so no, in my opinion there is no "mistake" there.

Comment: I have to wait 18 hours before I can give you the bounty. Isn't "mistake" the right English word?

Comment: I think it is the proper word, you could call it an "error" as well, but that's semantics ;)...but if the "required" somehow bothers you: just ignore it entirely, it doesn't really apply for the a-tag as you read yourself. so the "required"-part does not deal with what's allowed or not. Think of it like a form input, it can be required or not, that's one thing, but then what is allowed as a value (let's say an email) is something else, right?